# Как заполнить список с NaN?

Tags: python, list

Как получить список `list` с 100 `NaN`?

```
list = [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN ........ ]
```

Comment: `list = [float('nan') for _ in range(100)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.full(shape=100, fill_value=np.nan)
```

Answer (score 4):

`nan` можно получить так: `float('nan')`. Для получения списка повторяющихся элементов можно использовать или list comprehension:

```
x = [float('nan') for _ in range(100)]
```

или `repeat` из `itertools`:

```
from itertools import repeat

x = list(repeat(float('nan'), 100))
```

или через "умножение" списка:

```
x = [float('nan')] * 100
```

Comment: А еще можно так `list = [float('nan')] * 100` :)

Comment: <s>Можно, но не нужно.</s> Можно, но я не люблю такой способ создания списков.

Comment: Ну во-первых это не красиво. Не понятно, зачем создавать список из целого одного элемента, чтобы потом сразу уничтожить его.

Comment: я, честно говоря, не знаю как оно там под капотом работает, но не выглядит ли оно эффективнее?

Comment: Совсем не выглядит.

Comment: ну и ладно ¯\(°_o)/¯....

Comment: `list = [float('nan')] * 100` так быстрей https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzc1s4SLq6AoM69EA8LTg1AaShUKtgrRaTn5iSUa6nmJeeqasVqGBgZKmppEKldIyy9SiFfIzFMoSsxLT9UAataMBWpX@P8fAA

Comment: @Danis, `repeat` с преобразованием в список всего в два раза медленнее, но без преобразования в список в три раза быстрее.

Comment: быстрее потому что значения ещё не созданы, единственный действия это вызов функции

Comment: Ок, убедили, добавил в ответ